# How to use your iPad as an input pen tablet paired with an iMac?

Tags: macos, ipad, mac

I currently own an iPad pro with an Apple Pencil, and I must say that Apple Pencil's accuracy is one of the best in the market. I am an illustartor and I don't have any WACOM tablets right now, so can I use my iPad as the input tablet and use it just like any other digital pen table and make illustrations in Adobe illustrator?

Comment: [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/pro/) in the Pro version is able to do this, albeit pretty expensive.

Comment: @Daniel Isn't there any other way without the involvement of 3rd party apps?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not (yet) part of the system, otherwise there would be no need for 3rd party software. Another alternative is [Astropad](https://astropad.com/). We can only hope Apple will decide to buy one of the two companies to add value to their Mac+iPad line

Comment: isn't there a free app, both above recommendations are quite expensive for me as a student.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with some commercial 3rd party apps:

- [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/pro/) is an iOS / OS X app combo (about $20) that makes it possible to use an iPad as an external monitor connected to your mac. The "Pro" version (about $20 per year) provides the requested feature to use the iPad as a graphics tablet. By "mirroring" to the external monitor (iPad) in display settings, one gets the same view on the graphics tablet as on the Mac's screen.
- [Astropad](https://astropad.com/) is another combo (about $30) that focuses more on the graphics tablet idea. You cannot use it as an external monitor, but define an area of your Mac's screen that is mirrored to the tablet.  Apparently, the basic version can already be used as a graphics tablet, but the "Studio" version (about $80 per year) provides dedicated Apple pencil support for the iPad Pro, support for custom tool palettes and some additional gizmos.

Duet also offers a Windows version. However, according to the testimonials on the internet is has a much higher lag and is barely usable.

Comment: Astropad has a free version for use on iPhone/iPod, [Astropad Mini](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/astropad-mini-drawing-tablet/id1024285651?mt=8), this is a good way to test its speed and control